NextAuth with Next.js strange issue on middleware
I'm trying to build proper authentication, but there is a problem this works on google chrome but not on any other browser like edge or firefox.
The code:
"use client"

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { analytics } from "./lib/utilities/analytics";

export default async function Middleware(req: NextRequest) {

  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const session = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")

  if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=${path}`, req.nextUrl));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();

}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/dashboard/:path*"
      ]
};


The failed message i'm getting on firefox is:
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
with a secondary issue to many calls but, I have check the code and debugged it and its not the calls it makes because if I comment it out. the problem go away

if (!session) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=${path}, req.nextUrl));
}

I think this is the main root cause of the issue because the site wil get send to
https://webiste.com/login?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Fdashboard
I did my own debugging and have asked some developers around me to check the code and they tell me almost the same story I'm explaining.
